# disable IntelliJ backward analysis

Tags: intellij-idea

I've enabled some Inspection in IntelliJ IDEA that is now causing a lengthy **backward analysis**. Do you know which inspections cause this? Thanks

Comment: what's the message it shows when performing the operation?

Comment: After running Inspection, it gets stuck with a dialog processing **...Performing backward analysis dependencies...**. I'd post a screen shot, but now I reverted all my inspections and can't seem to reproduce it, nor really want or have the time to go through the whole ordeal again. I should probably just delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably checked the Declaration Redundancy -> Unused libraries option. That always triggers backward analysis for me usually leading to an OutOfMemoryError situation.

Comment: Uddhav, you were right! Now 2 years later I encountered the same exact problem setting up another IntelliJ inspection profile. The other issue that I was having is that I have to remember to click Apply before exiting the inspection settings